# How to get status of socket.id in node.js like connected or not?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

mobile application can send socket id like : bBQPfAsfm9hLw6rBAAAB
i need to get status of this id like connected or not

```
var http = require('http');
var app = http.createServer().listen(4000),
io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log("client has established :" + socket.id);
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
console.log("client has disconnected :" + socket.id);
});       
});
```

this my code and i don't need this..!!
i need to check status of socket id

like : every time my socket id is diffrent...

```
var socket_id = "bBQPfAsfm9hLw6rBAAAB"; // every time diffrent socket id
if(socket.status == "true"){
    alert("connected");
}
else{
  echo "not connected";
}
```

any one can help me ... i want to integration

if this is not possible than please let me how to store badges in group chat ...
like  ex: room1 and user is user1 and user2 if user 1 is two messaged on user2 and user 2 is not connected than store 2 bages on user 2.

if you understan than give me solution of this....